# Javascript Syntax Error: Unexpected token -

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, unexpected-token

I know it maybe a simple error but, I have looked at it for hours and, could not find the error. Here is the snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  "use strict";
  $('#jumbobtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url : '/create/name',
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: null,
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(reply, status, xhr){
        if(reply['error']!==undefined){
          throw new Error('No template given');
        }
        if(reply['success']!==undefined){
          $('#createform').append( reply['cform'] ).css({ display : 'block' });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Are you including a reference to JQuery?

Comment: Can you show your jQuery import please?

Comment: the jquery is actually part of the parent template. this template was sent as  a rendered string from the server side as an addition to the currently serving template. I'm using ejs. Is that  going to be problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yea I put this into an html file. There was an error, but not unexpected token. I had to import jquery. After that everything was fine. Maybe your unexpected token was somewhere else.

Comment: that's a possibility i was hoping not get into. the problem is that this snippet is part of an ejs partial template and, it is being used along with many other such partials into a parent template. could you suggest a good way to approach writing test? i'm using ejs with express btw.

Comment: I don't test too much in js so I can't give too much advice. Sorry. I read that you load the jquery via the parent template, so it should be fine for that, unless you are using this partial without the parent. It could be useful to copy and past the error as no one else is getting it. otherwise, like I said before, I strongly thing it has to do with something outside the snippet.